# Is there a way to save Airi's Father?

Tags: devil-survivor-2

So I found Airi's father bleeding on the ground after he accidentally summoned some high level demons.  I wasn't sure exactly when the event was opened up but I did it at 1700.  My previous save was 5 hours ago (at 1200) and I'm wondering if I could have saved him if I made it on time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't played my copy of DS2, but [this is the info my google-fu has yielded](http://megamitensei.wikia.com/wiki/Dera-Deka#Devil_Survivor_2).

**No, [you can't save him by making it on time](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/625210-/62412072). He has [fixed events in a fixed order with some at fixed times](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/625210-/62269284).**

**[You can maybe save him by not following his events](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/625210-/62273002) because he presumably doesn't try to summon Jikokuten.**

**You need him to die in order to save him. [If you proceed through all his events, he can be seen alive during the Daichi+ ending.](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/625210-/62338598)** You essentially need to get your team to fate 4, follow the Dera Deka events and choose the restoration ending if I read correctly. You may need to recruit everyone as well when doing so or maybe that's just to see the complete ending for all characters.